# When does greediness guarantee optimality?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, greedy-algorithms, searching, matroids

I was wondering if there is any theoretical results characterizing under what condition does greedy algorithm actually finds the optimal solution.

Here is a motivating example. Suppose you are trying to find

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2} f(x)$$

where $f$ is convex, and the minimizer happens to be on an integer point $(a,b)$. You start from $(0,0)$ and at each iteration you are allowed to walk to one of the 4 integer points next to you.

The **greedy** algorithm is that, at each iteration $t$, you check the 4 points and walk to the one with the lowest objective value.

Now, here is a **condition** under which greedy method actually gives you the shortest path to find the minimum:

For any $x_1$, $x_2$, such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$, we have $min_{x \mbox{ next to } x_1} f(x)\leq min_{x \mbox{ next to } x_2} f(x)$.

So can the above condition be generalized to other settings? Or are there any general conditions that characterize such optimality? Quick google search didn't give me anything useful.

Comment: Check out the notion of a **matroid**.

Comment: If the order of the choices is irrelevant, then greedy algorithms find the optimal solution (e.g. given a set of numbers, find the three element subset with the largest sum). If, at a given state, every option results in the same next state, a greedy algorithm will find an optimal solution.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX, could you elaborate? I didn't quite understand your example.

Comment: @Moritz, that popped up in my search, but I don't have much knowledge about it. Any recommended text?

Comment: @Xuezhou Zhang: Take a look at the following 4 links: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/shortcourse/2011/crypto.pdf 
http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/klappi/csce411-f13/csce411-set5b.pdf 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm 
http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/08-matroids.pdf

Comment: Did you want a condition to guarantee that you find a minimum, or also that you find the shortest path to the minimum?  A sufficient condition for the former: If every local optimum is a global optimum, then the greedy method will find the minimum for you (though not necessarily the shortest path to the minimum).

Comment: @D.W., Of course, I want the shortest path as well.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid There are also some work on modeling what is a greedy algorithm.